# why this code does not work although all steps are true?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: why this code does not work]

why this code does not work although all steps are true ??

```
def start_with(long,short):
    for position in range(len(short)):
        if long[position] != short[position]:
            return False
    return True

start_with("banana","ba")
```

Comment: I ran your code. It returns true. Did you mean to print something?

Comment: does not get any output with me

Comment: @RaafatMostafa Try `print(start_with("banana", "ba"))`

Comment: This code doesn't actually return anything to make it return something use this code `print(start_with("banana", "ba"))`

Comment: Having the value of an expression statement printed to the terminal is a property of the interactive interpreter, not Python in general.

Comment: @RaafatMostafa: What output do you expect to see and why?

Comment: Thanks Barmar , Webify

Comment: i saw this function in video and get true without using print statement . Can you tell me ??

Comment: @Webify Please don't confuse printing with returning.

Comment: @khelwood how this code get true with you and me no.

Comment: @RaafatMostafa: Your function is *returning* `True`, but you're not *printing* it.

Comment: @RaafatMostafa Your function returns true. So *returning* works fine. Your program doesn't *print* anything because you don't tell it to print anything. Printing is different from returning.

Comment: @khelwood That is what I was saying that the function itself returns True but doesnt actually print it, for him to see the result `print` would be needed.

Comment: @khelwood Ok.,,